# How to specify/organize/clean up jar libraries in projects well

Tags: java, jar

When we develop a project, if we want to use `struts` or `tiles` or `spring` or anything else, we have to import some jaf files (into project build path or lib folder)

So I want to ask, is there any website/tool that specify which .jar files we need for each purpose so that I don't have to add a lot of jar files into my project

I'm sorry if this question is irrelevant. I just don't know where to ask :(

Nice day ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html). It is a build/dependency management tool which enables you not to download any dependencies manually, you just have to define it in a configuration file that you need a specific version of a library and it takes care of it all. Also you can use a number of so called [archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) which are basically skeleton applications for a specific set of technologies.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying with Maven :)

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with *abalogh*

Use Maven or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) & [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) for your needs

When you turn into serious development, you can go without these tools. Test both and choose whichever is good for you. Don't listen to trolls about this or this technology (Mine is better ! No, it's Mine), go to websites, learn to use and make your choice. Then stick to it to get the best out the tool you choose

Cheers

Grooveek

Comment: did you mean "you can't go without these tools" ?